# better html watermark mechanism for input and textareas

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, webforms

I'm using [jquery.watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-watermark/) for adding watermarks for html form inputs.  I love it, really easy to use as a developer and makes the site easier to use for visitors.  Problem is, for some browsers, people are submitting forms with fields that are supposed to be left empty... but they get submitted with the watermark text!  That is an **absolute dealbreaker** problem and I'm going to have to stop using this watermark unfortunately because of it.

Are there any other mechanisms which do not exhibit this behavior, at least not in any modern browser (including IE6+)?  I prefer jQuery, but any mechanism will do.  I assume javascript is necessary..

***UPDATE***: I think I'm going to go with [jq-watermark](http://code.google.com/p/jq-watermark/), unless there are better mechanisms someone knows about or there's something wrong with this?  It looks great:

- supports individualized css
- supports html5's placeholder attribute as a fallback mechanism, which I was unaware of
- uses a mechanism which doesn't allow for submitting watermarks to the server
- has an elegant feel which fades the watermark with focus and only removes when entering text

***UPDATE 2***: Unfortunately, looks like the jq-watermark plugin doesn't actually work well at all... at least not for me and I have a pretty standard setup.  Maybe there's a conflict with other javascript, but I doubt it.  I really like their feature set, particularly the html5 fallback.  In fact, I like the html5 fallback so much that I'm tempted to just forget about a javascript mechanism for this and only have this for html5 browsers.  But not even firefox has this html5 feature yet, only safari and chrome as far as I can see :(.  That's only 10% or so of my visitors...

***UPDATE 3***: I've finally been able to get jq-watermark to work well.  I've had to add some CSS rules to its classes and adopt some html conventions (like using a div container instead of setting the width on an input element).  The reason the html5 fallback mechanism wasn't working and I was experiencing weird behavior was that you can't rely on the automatic application of jq-watermark to all elements with the class jq_watermark, in fact it's harmful to have any elements with that class if you want to use the placeholder attribute.  Instead you have to call `$(selectors).watermark('placeholder text', {fallback:true});`.  Kind of sucks because you have to duplicate the placeholder text in that call and on the placeholder attribute.  But, of course, you can use jQuery's .each() to read that attribute.  Also, on firefox, the fading upon focus looks somewhat bad... but Firefox 4 will have placeholder html5 support, so I'm not too worried.  The font changes a little as well frequently when focusing on an input element.

A bit disappointing having wasted a good few hours testing all the solutions out there and having a pretty poor choice for such a simple mechanism.  jq-watermark, after tweaking it and your html, is probably the best solution there is.

Comment: Can you describe in greater detail what's not working for you? Also, it's not that hard to implement the features of jq-watermark if you want to - it certainly won't be as full featured, but the basic idea is pretty simple

Comment: well, I guess first, the design gets all screwed up... I briefly looked at it with firefox and for one I sometimes need to float and/or adjust the width on my input elements.  That appears to definitely have disastrous consequences with jq-watermark.  But even if I enclose my input within a div, the text looks funny.  #2, the autodetection of html5's placeholder doesn't work (yes I set that option to true).  And the adding of the jq-watermark doesn't automatically invoke this plugin (not important, but nothing seems to work right).

Answer (score 1):

I built a really simple jQuery plugin for this sort thing, it isn't that difficult. This uses the `title` attribute for the placeholder text but that is pretty easy to change.

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.egText = function(options) {
        options  = $.extend({ }, $.fn.egText.defaults, options || { });
        var $all = this;
        $all.focus(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if(!$this.data(options.dataKey))
                    $this.data(options.dataKey, 'yes').removeClass(options.egClass).val('');
            })
            .blur(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if($this.val() == '')
                    $this.addClass(options.egClass).removeData(options.dataKey).val($this.attr('title'));
                else
                    $this.data(options.dataKey, 'yes');
            })
            .blur();
        $.unique($all.closest('form')).submit(function() {
            $all.each(function() {
                var $this = $(this);
                if(!$this.data(options.dataKey))
                    $this.val('');
            });
            return true;
        });
    };

    $.fn.egText.defaults = {
        dataKey: 'egText',  // The key we use for storing our state with .data(), just in case there are conflicts...
        egClass: 'lolite'   // The CSS class to add to the <input> when we're displaying the example text.
    };

})(jQuery);
```

You're welcome to use this if it does what you need. I don't know if it works in IE6 but it does work in the latest Firefox, Safari, Opera, Chrome, IE7, and IE8.

Answer (score 0):

[This jQuery Watermark plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/updnWatermark) does not alter the value of the input fields. So you should be safe using it.

Comment: Love the concept, thanks!  don't like how I can't specify a css class for individual elements and it's an all or nothing application.. not very jquery-like.  Also, this hasn't been updated in a year and a half and the comments mention important features and bugs without a response.  I'm going to play with this and make sure that last bug mentioned in the comments isn't going to be a problem as it looks like will..